# Get 404 1668 in CMD and can't connect my css file im html

Tags: python, html, css, django

Here's my script in base.html, the left of the picture is about my tree.
I checked the href should be correct and I've load static at very top of the html file. However I still cannot connect the css file anyone can help he here? Thanks!

```
href="{% static 'Simple_Social/css/master.css' %}"
```

for refer, please see the picture since idk why I can't post a picture yet, thanks!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi2z6.png

Comment: Is this supposed to be django

Comment: yes it's django and I just updated the post for the link of the picture

Comment: What do you have "STATIC" related variables in settings.py ?

Comment: STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static') ,
STATIC_URL = '/static/'  , 
STATIC_ROOT = STATIC_DIR

Comment: its STATICFILES_DIRS not STATIC_DIR

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Though I set up STATIC_DIR as a variable to grab the directory for STATIC_ROOT to refer, not to set it as STATICFILES_DIRS.
Somehow I change STATIC_ROOT to  STATICFILES_DIRS and run django-admin collectstatic then it worked.
However I think that my real problem hasn't been resolved, why can't I connect the css file through STATIC_ROOT?

Answer (score 0):

This is how static files are configured. In settings.py file inside the INSTALLED_APPS list, there is an app called 'django.contrib.staticfiles', this baked in app manages the static files across the entire project during development as well in production.

This static URL will append to base URL for serving static files in development like http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/style.css basically think this as a reference to static files.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

STATICFILES_DIRS tells Django the location of static files in our project. The common practice is to have all the static files in a top-level static directory.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), ]
```

STATIC_ROOT is the single root directory from where the Django application will serve the static files in production. The command manage.py collectstatic will automatically compile all the static files throughout the project and dump it into a single root directory, which is declared in STATIC_ROOT.

```
STATIC_ROOT  = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Finally, you can user load static to load the static files in template

```
{% load static %}
```